# How to uninstall microsoft web developer tools in extension manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

My VS 2012 Update 1 launches totally slow, even I have upgraded to Update 2, it is still the same. So, I guess (maybe wrong) because some extensions in VS 2012 crashed, I cannot uninstall them.

[image]

On the picture, I have 2 extensions crashed (Uninstall button is disable):

1. Microsoft Web Developer Tool.
2. Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript.

Is there any way that I am able to uninstall both?

I also follow the hint on the bottom-right corner to uninstall in Programs and Features, but I cannot find.

Comment: Look under 'Updates' in Programs and Features.

Comment: @leppie: thanks for your comment, regret that I cannot find them in Updates

Comment: Have you used "run as administrator" when you run VS?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: yes, I have

Answer (score 14):

Same issue here as well. A registry search uncovered the command to uninstall Microsoft Web Developer Tools 2012.2 - Visual Studio 2012. This is the UninstallString:

```
MsiExec.exe /X{8762B098-374D-4900-B68E-34BF2840E694}
```

Just copy to the command line (make sure you run command line as administrator) and hit enter.

For the Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript, the command is:

```
MsiExec.exe /x{1228E4A3-8371-4F9B-BA6F-3D34113811B9}
```

HTH

Comment: I uninstalled the Microsoft Web Developer Tools 2012.2 - Visual Studio 2012 by mistake may i know how to re-install it.Thanks

Comment: As of VS2012 Update 4 the product GUID for `Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript` seems to be `{23F9C27A-E520-4C87-AF99-E5A7D021F24A}`.

Comment: For Web Developer Tools 2013 - Visual Studio 2013 the product GUID is {BD63060C-F4C7-4E86-9C2A-4A102E7EE12C}

Comment: It also goes under this GUID sometimes as well, it seems (the JavaScript extension library, that is): {D5FEB7A1-5D0F-4CDC-8290-F52DFB53AF23}

Comment: ... and also {7CB4CF88-6C28-479F-BBD4-53065ACA4583}

Comment: Actually kept getting update notifications in Visual Studio until I uninstalled the JS Extensions Library with GUID {D5FEB7A1-5D0F-4CDC-8290-F52DFB53AF23}